# Matching exactly option and optgroup

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I got an issue with following script when the select-options become long:

> Solution with few options http://jsfiddle.net/hsQjh/5/
>
> Long options with issue: http://jsfiddle.net/hsQjh/6/

My first select-box option is up to 40+ of options, thus the second select-box would be up to 40+ of optgroup as well, when I picked option '**2**' on first box, second box are populated all optgroup that is numbered started with 2, which is optgroup '**2**', '**20**' - '**29**' are populated, the same are happen to other options which is had selected too.

Could it be match the 'IDs' exactly in between option's value and optgroup's label?

```
function filterActivity(e){
     var ids = $('#filterActivity + div input:checked').map(function(i) {
        return $(this).val().replace(/ .*/, '');
     }).get(); // Retrieve checked IDs

     $('#filterSubActivity + div div label').each(function() { // Show matching options
        $(this).toggle($.inArray($('input', this).val()[0], ids) > -1);
     });

     $('#filterSubActivity + div label.optGroup').each(function() { // Show matching groups
        $(this).toggle($(this).next().find('label:visible').length > 0);
     });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex based filter

```
$('#filterSubActivity + div div label').each(function() { // Show matching options
    $(this).toggle($.inArray($('input', this).val().match(/^\d+/)[0], ids) > -1);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lxmbz/)